# steps to enable e-commerce in brochure website

Tags: magento-community

I'm not very experienced with Magento.

I've received a client who is using Magento Community, and has existing Magento products, but the front end buttons all say "Enquire Now >", rather than "add to cart".

Also, the prices are not set yet.

Please correct my current understanding. I need to:

1. Export the products using something like [this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/custom-bulk-product-import-export-with-tier-pricing-product-custom-options-configurable-products-bundle-products-grouped-products-downloadable.html).
2. Add correct price.
3. Import products.
4. (Potentially install &) configure payment gateway.
5. Done.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Steve, it's really impossible to say exactly what you should do without more info. I.e. do you know how the buttons were swapped; do you know how to switch them back? Are there really enough products to require an export/import?

Comment: @ReidBlomquist: I did a search of a complete file backup for the search term `Enquire Now >` (the button text), and nothing was found. Odd. There are about 963 products.

Comment: @steve , i think you dont have to go through all this , the magento would have been just customized for inquire , go through the view.phtml compare it with original view.phtml and configure payment gateway

Comment: Beaut! Thanks @VishwasBhatnagar! I was searching for `Enquire Now >`. I needed to search for `Enquire Now &gt;`. Customisation was in `app\design\frontend\default\modern\template\catalog\product\view.phtml` as you said.

Comment: Can't you use new template? if not you can replace Enquire Now > <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?>. it seems you are using magento modern template, try to replace it from Magento default installation

Comment: @Steve thanks I am posting the Answer then , please accept the answer and award bounty to me :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find the original "Add to Cart" button here:

```
/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml
```

Copy this file into the corresponding place in your theme, eg:

```
/app/design/frontend/PACKAGE/THEME/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml
```

(You might find this file is already there.)

Then we need to add this file back into the product page. This is done with this two stage process:

First edit your `local.xml` file, which you should find here:

```
/app/design/frontend/PACKAGE/THEME/layout/local.xml
```

And add the following to it:

```
<reference name="product.info">
    <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.addtocart" as="addtocart" template="catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

Then open up your product view page, which you should find here:

```
/app/design/frontend/PACKAGE/THEME/template/catalog/product/view.phtml
```

And add the follow code to it, where you want the add to cart button to appear:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product.info.addtocart'); ?>
```

That should get you your add to cart button back. All of this is assuming your version of Magento hasnt been altered too much from its defaults.

---

As for changing the prices, this can be done in the Admin Panel. If you would rather change the prices in a spreadsheet, then go to `System > Import / Export > Export` to generate a CSV file that can be opened in something like OpenOffice. Then you can use the same system to import the CSV file without having to install an extension.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Your installation might have been just customized to show "Enquire Now" Compare the view.phtml (`app\design\frontend\default\modern\template\catalog\product\view.phtml`) file with the original Magento file , And configure payment gateway. you will be all set to switch back website to catalog mode